# Eliminar objeto de lista PHP

Tags: php, php7

trato de eliminar una objeto de la `lista(array)` en `PHP` pero deja `null` y no se borra, he intentado tambien com `array_diff`, `array_splice` pero es igual, siempre se queda `null`,

```
$data = ["asda","asdfsdf","sadfsdf"];
//result
$data = [null, null ,null];
//objetivo
$data = [];
```

**Código**

```
        $lista = $this->data;
        unset($lista[$pos]);
        $lista = array_map(function ($dd) {
            if ($dd != null || $dd != "null") {
                return $dd;
            }
        }, $lista);
        $this->data = array_values($lista);
```

Comment: El problema es que estás usando `array_map()`, que sirve para recorrer todos los elementos del arreglo, sin filtrar. Intenta con [`array_filter()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: @Triby es el mismo problema, aunque si se retiran los primeros, pero no todos, no se porque se queda en `[null]`, siempre el ultimo se convierte en `null`

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que quieres es eliminar todos los elementos solo tienes que asignar un arreglo vacío:

```
<?php
$data = ["asda","asdfsdf","sadfsdf"];
$data = [];
print_r($data);
```

Resultado:

```
Array ()
```

Si nada más necesitas eliminar los que tengan valor `null` o `"null"` usa la función [array_reduce()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-reduce.php):

```
<?php
$data = ["asda", null, "asdfsdf", "null", "sadfsdf"];
$data = array_reduce($data, function($carry, $item) {
    if($item !== null && $item != "null") {
        // Agregar a arreglo solo si no es valor nulo
        $carry[] = $item;
    }
    return $carry;
}, []);
print_r($data);
```

Resultado:

```
Array (
    [0] => asda
    [1] => asdfsdf
    [2] => sadfsdf
)
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución efectivamente se resuelve con el `array_filter`, como ya te dijeron. Prueba esto:

```
$data = ["asda","asdfsdf","sadfsdf"];

$result = array_filter($data, function($item) {
    unset($item);
});

print_r(array_values($result));
```

Verás como te devuelve un array vacío. Acá te dejo el [script funcional donde lo probé](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/637865c622279d30490385ecb61c5b52a73ab9e2)

Comment: sigue devoliendo igual `[null,null,null]`

Comment: No, eso devuelve un array vacío. Acá [lo probé](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/637865c622279d30490385ecb61c5b52a73ab9e2)